# Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank DeviseCreateAdminUsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I've reviewed all previous posts and answers to this one but stumped at this point. Any help appreciated. This happens when running migrations for ActiveAdmin, Rails 4, Ruby 2.0 all recent stable versions.

```
==  DeviseCreateAdminUsers: migrated (0.1006s) ================================

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank ~/db/migrate/20131108204716_devise_create_admin_users.rb:5:in `migrate'
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank
~/db/migrate/20131108204716_devise_create_admin_users.rb:5:in `migrate'
```

- Rails 4.0.2
- ruby 2.1.5p273
- devise (3.2.4)
- activeadmin 1.0.0.pre from git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git (at master)

I've added suggested fix to **admin_user.rb** but still fails:

```
controller do
  def permitted_params
    params.permit admin_user: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation]
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include links to the questions or posts you've already consulted and explain what about those posts either didn't work for you or you didn't understand.

Comment: This is one of the threads from activeadmin at github but none of these have worked for me: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2284

Comment: Just check your database if it is having a blank entry in the users table in which email and password is blank. If it exists then delete it and retry. May be this resolves the issue.

Comment: db is empty. this is from uninitialized db using rake db:migrate.

Comment: Please paste your migration code of `20131108204716_devise_create_admin_users.rb` here in the question.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AtomSmash/f334869feb2a26118bd0